# Update SQL server row only if column is not a 1 or 0 bit

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I would like to update a row that contains a serial number(string), a boolean(bit) only if the bit is 0 (aka false), and a date(date). I want this to be done server side so that a user would not be able alter the row after that row has been set to false. Otherwise, the row is freely editable while that row is set to 1 (aka true).

I have tried writing a trigger that does this for me, however I cannot get it to parse a row before it is update in order to determine whether or not it should write to that row.

For example,

Row 1: SN = 123456,  TorF = 1, Date = 01-31-2015 :: this would be able to be edited/updated for a newer date

Row 2: SN = 654321, TorF = 0, Date = 03-31-2015 :: this would not be able to be changed and would throw an error to the user

EDIT: 
Here is what I have tried

```
CREATE TRIGGER DisallowOnFailEdit
ON myTable
INSTEAD OF UPDATE
AS
IF EXISTS(SELECT myColumn FROM LoopBackCable WHERE myColumn = 0)
    THROW 50000, 'Cable has been permanently retired', 1
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
```

Comment: Use an "INSTEAD OF" trigger.

Comment: I have tried that to no avail. I have posted the trigger that I have gotten some result from. I have only been using SQL for a few days now. Excuse my ignorance of any basics.

Comment: That's your entire trigger code?   With INSTEAD OF, you need to perform the original UPDATE in the trigger code, if the logic dictates it.  You don't need to rollback.   As the name implies, the code in the trigger is executed instead of the original UPDATE that was executed by the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the deleted table for this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER DisallowOnFailEdit
ON myTable
FOR UPDATE
AS
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM DELETED WHERE myColumn = 0)
BEGIN
    THROW 50000, 'Cable has been permanently retired', 1
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
END
```

Or the same with instead of trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER DisallowOnFailEdit
ON myTable
INSTEAD OF UPDATE
AS
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INSERTED i
          JOIN myTable m on i.PK = m.PK WHERE m.myColumn = 0)
BEGIN
    THROW 50000, 'Cable has been permanently retired', 1
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
END


UPDATE m
    SET Col1 = i.Col1,
        Col2 = i.Col2
    ....
FROM INSERTED i
JOIN myTable m on i.PK = m.PK
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. I swore I had tried the first solution you have posted by utilizing the DELETED table. Regardless, you have solved my problem. Thanks again.